# Javascript SDK: Facebook Login Dialog disappears immediately

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm facing a weird issue when asking users for additional permissions. The Login Dialog pops up but disappears very quickly and user can't see it.

This only happen to normal users but working fine for Admin/Developer accounts.

Code:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
FB.api('/me/permissions', function(response){
    console.log(response.data);

});

}, {scope: 'publish_actions' });
```

Comment: You need to get publish_actions approved by Facebook before you can ask normal users

Comment: this is the correct answer. Thanks!